# How to update a database column based on the device's location?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-room

I've been working on a map based app, and so far the application gets the data of markers from a Room database as a LiveData object and draws the markers on the map and gets the device's location through a FusedLocationProviderClient.

Now I have tried to create a method that would update a column in the database from 0 to 1 if the device reaches a marker, making the marker "active" and then displaying the marker's name as a toast if that marker's "active" column equals to 1.

So far I have tried to use `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(LatLng1, LatLng2) < distance`  and if the condition is met, then it calls a method to update the column, but I have not managed to get it to work, as the devices location keeps changing and the markers come from a LiveData List object which are both checked for changes and I don't know how to use these in the computeDistanceBetween method. I have gone through the documents related to markers and other map based objects but so far I have not found a solution.

Here is the method that retrieves and draws the markers on the map.

```
markerViewModel.getAllMarkers().observe(this, new Observer<List<MarkerObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MarkerObject> markerObjects) {
                for (MarkerObject markerObject : markerObjects) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerObject.getLatitude(), markerObject.getLongitude());
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .title(markerObject.getTitle())
                                .position(latLng)
                                .visible(true));
                    }
                }
        });
```

the methods that get and draw the device's location on the map.

```
/**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        getLocationPermission();
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                lastKnownLocation = null;

            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
     */
    public void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            lastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to reach a solution for quite a while through many trials but to no success, I really hope someone can help because I am out of ideas. Any help is well appreciated. Also I don't ask for help in just any case but with this I really am struggling, so literally any documentation or piece of info that would help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I have previously used to check the distance between location objects, you can use it as it is or modify it to your needs, the code is pretty straight forward.

```
    public final boolean isLocationCloseEnough(Location currentLocation, Location markerLocation, double distance) {
        // this is where the method stores the distance between the two locations
        float[] distanceInMeters = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), markerLocation.getLatitude(), markerLocation.getLongitude(), distanceInMeters);
        return (double)distanceInMeters[0] < distance;
    }
```

To be able to request location updates you need a location Request like so and request location updates

```
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(5);
    LocationCallback callback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            // here is the location
            Location lastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            // do what needs to be done
        }
    };


    public void sample() {
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callback, Looper.getMainLooper());
    }
```

Finally when your activity or fragment pauses make sure to remove/stop the updates like so

```
        client.removeLocationUpdates(callback)
```

You can find more information on LocarionRequest here, and play around with its configurations, https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest

Comment: Thank you for the method, but my issue is how do I get the currentLocation if it changes. If I return the current location from the getDeviceLocation, then it is the location at one moment but how do I continuously check the condition if the currentLocation changes?

Comment: I edited my answer to show location updates