# Android Studio Emulator Returning Null Location Data

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gps

I'm learning Kotlin, and I'm trying to make a simple app that displays the users long/lat. Everything seems like it should be working, but the location data keeps throwing the 'null else{}' case. Below is what my code looks like.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val RequestPermissionCode = 1
var mLocation: Location? = null
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    getLastLocation()
}

fun getLastLocation(){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermission()
    }
    else{
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener {location: Location? ->
                    mLocation = location
                    if(location != null){
                        latitude.text = location.latitude.toString()
                        longitude.text = location.longitude.toString()
                    }
                    else{
                        latitude.text = "LOCATION_DENIED"
                        longitude.text = "LOCATION_DENIED"
                    }
                }
    }
}

private fun requestPermission(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), RequestPermissionCode)
    this.recreate()
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm about to start pulling my hair out, and can't find the answers on Google ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulators I have noticed have issues with Location data, plus lastLocation is not making a location request, so there is good chance there is no location data. What you need is requestLocationUpdate method, so that it can retrieve active location of the user. Also you will have better luck on a physical device for last Location.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much, your comment has definitely set me in the right direction! I just verified that your hypothesis is correct, as when I launch the Google maps app to update my location, and then re-open my own app, the location is there. So now I just need to figure out how to implement a location update method

Comment: I answered a question here before on location updates, have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164852/how-to-update-a-database-column-based-on-the-devices-location/66165828#66165828

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out! This line of code fixed it: fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)